# Multiplication of algebraic fraction not giving desired result

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I am having a try at solving this:

[image: (1+(2x/y)+(x^2/y^2))*(y^3)/(x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3)]

that supposed to return:

[image: y/x+y]

but I get stuck at:

[image]

which can be written as

[image]

Comment: The term $x^{3} + 3x^{2}y + 3xy^{2} + y^{3} = (x+y)^{3}$

Comment: I recommend you take a look at binomial theorem. It'll explain why that term is equal to $(x+y)^3$

Comment: OP I think there's an error in your last image. I think the $3x^3y$ should be $3x^2y$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:$$x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3=(x+y)^3$$

Comment: Thank you so much, it's right!!! :)